# How to export value per URL to different XML-files

Tags: xml, powershell, api

I have a script to fetch API data from multiple URL:s (I can't fetch all since it is limited to a specific amount)
I am able to export using Transcript to one file all data from all URL:s (100 pages with 1000 posts per page).
But we need to export all data from one URL to one file and the next URL to antother file etc.
I tried with below code to preform this action but I get 2 files (using two URL:s) but all data is in the first file.
Not quite sure how to sort this out.

```
Import-Module pscx
function Ignore-SelfSignedCerts
{
    try
    {
        #Write-Host "Adding TrustAllCertsPolicy type." -ForegroundColor White
        Add-Type -TypeDefinition  @"
        using System.Net;
        using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
        public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy
        {
             public bool CheckValidationResult(
             ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
             WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
             {
                 return true;
            }
        }
"@
        #Write-Host "TrustAllCertsPolicy type added." -ForegroundColor White
      }
    catch
    {
        #Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    }
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
}
Ignore-SelfSignedCerts

$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$Uri = "https://prime/webacs/api/v1/data/Clients?.firstResult=0&.maxResults=1&.full=true,
https://prime/webacs/api/v1/data/Clients?.firstResult=2&.maxResults=1&.full=true"
$separator = ","
$urlList = $Uri.Split($separator, $option)

function Get-BasicAuthCreds {
    param([string]$Username,[string]$Password)
    $AuthString = "{0}:{1}" -f $Username,$Password
    $AuthBytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii.GetBytes($AuthString)
    return [Convert]::ToBase64String($AuthBytes)
}
$BasicCreds = Get-BasicAuthCreds -Username "User" -Password "Password"

$StartNum = 0
$Result = $null

$Result = foreach ($url in $urlList){
    Start-Transcript -Path "C:\Data\URL\$StartNum.xml"
    $DataURL = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $BasicCreds"}
    Write-Host $DataURL
    # Give feedback on how far we are
    Write-Host ("Initiated request for {0}" -f $url)  
    $StartNum++
    cls
    Stop-Transcript
    $DataURL = $null
}
```

Comment: For me Transcript is working, but you may  note that inside foreach loop your variable `$result` is always empty because it takes value only in end your loop.And move `Start-transcript` at begin foreach loop.

Comment: I commend out `$Result = $null` and placed `Start-transcript` at the begining of the foreach loop. I get data in both files created but same data. I want the data from the first URL to be placed in the first file and so on. Not all data in all files.

Comment: very strange but they cannot be the same because records occur in a cycle with a file change, you may have the same query result and therefore the files seem to be the same.

Comment: `Write-Host $Result` inside the loop doesn't make sense, since `$Result` is the variable that collects the data emitted from the loop itself. Question is, _what data do you want to collect? A mix of `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.BasicHtmlWebResponseObject`s from Invoke-WebRequest combined with confirmation messages from Start- and Stop-Transcript? (`Write-Host` only outputs messages in the console and returns nothing)

Comment: If I don't `Write-Host $Result` I don't get any data in the files. Se an example above.
I want to take all API data from the URL:s and export them to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.
I needed to place the data from the Web-Request to an variable which I cleared at the end of the loop each time. Above code is updated.